# Which is better: an additional mobile site or a fluid website optimized for both desktop and mobile?

Tags: mobile, web, fluid-layout

I have a fairly large dynamic website, whose user interface is written using `XHTML`, `CSS` and `jQuery`. The site does not display/work well on mobile devices. What is the best option: to develop a fluid site that displays well on both mobile and desktop, or to separately develop a mobile version of the site? Thank you for any suggestion.

Comment: Why the close vote? Voter care to say why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although a parallel site, with a desktop page and a mobile page is easier to build, it is harder to maintain (2 sets of content) and Google will see this as duplicate content - one of the sites won't rank in search engines.

A fluid solution, which displays the content well whatever the screen size (and if you use CSS & JavaScript wisely, it can look great on all sorts of screen sizes), is a much better solution, and you only have one URL for each page for your visitors to book mark.